# Did modern alligators and caimans come from prehistoric crocodiles?

Tags: evolution, phylogenetics, reptile

I know that crocodilians have been here since the time of the dinosaurs. I also know that crocodiles came first. But alligators have been here for a good 37 million years. Did alligators come from crocodiles when the crocs swam into freshwater areas?

And since the alligators and caimans are 2 groups in alligatoridae did they have a common ancestor?

And also if alligators came from crocodiles (which might or might not be true), why isn't it more like this:

Crocodylidae $\rightarrow$ Alligatoridae $\rightarrow$ Alligatorinae $\rightarrow$  Alligator

for alligators and

Crocodylidae $\rightarrow$ Crocodylus

for crocodiles?

Comment: The tree of crocodilomorpha is [here on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodylomorpha).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the phylogeny of the Crocodilia, as best as we currently know it:

The order *Crocodilia* is a monophyletic group including all living crocodile and alligator species. That means that all of these species share a common ancestor and all descendants of that ancestor are part of *Crocodilia*.

Within the *Brevirostres*, three superfamilies exist - the now extinct *Borealosuchus*, the *[Gavialoidea](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gavialoidea)*, within only two species not already extinct, and the [*Brevirostres*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brevirostres).

The *Brevirostres* are the monophyletic group containing the crocodiles and alligators (that includes the caimans).

> Did alligators come from crocodiles when the crocs swam into freshwater areas?

That very much depends on what you mean with "crocodile". If it's *Crocodylidae*, then no, these are sister groups. If it's only the true crocodiles (*Crocodylids*), no, those evolved after the split with alligators. If it's *Crocodilia*, then yes, alligators evolved from crocodiles.

> And since the alligators and caimans are 2 groups in alligatoridae did they have a common ancestor?

Yes. However, saying that is rather boring - all life has a common ancestor. If you mean whether they have a common ancestor and all descendants of that ancestor are either alligators or caiman, then yes.

Additional source: [Crocodilian phylogeny inferred from twelve mitochondrial protein-coding genes, with new complete mitochondrial genomic sequences for *Crocodylus acutus* and *Crocodylus novaeguineae*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1055790311001692)